# Uisng Linux Mint 21 OS ,I'm unable to get multicursor on holding the "Alt" key, left-click with my mouse at different locations. What to do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, linux-mint-21

**I'm using VS Code version 1.79.1**

**Facing issue in getting multicursor in the editor.**

Below I have gone through to achive the same :-

> By holding the "Alt" key, left-click with mouse at different locations in the file
> want the additional cursors to appear.

> Clicked at different locations, So I will see multiple cursors being created simultaneously.

But failed, Need help to resolve this issue .

Comment: 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. 2) show us the value of your `editor.multiCursorModifier` setting.

Comment: 3) What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.